# Unique characters from string

Tags: java

I am trying to print all the unique characters from a string but I am not getting proper output. Also, I want to check if someone enters integer in string, I want to print Invalid String. How can I achieve this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    char[] ch = new char[20];
    System.out.println("Enter the sentence:");
    String sent = sc.nextLine().replaceAll(" ", "");
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < sent.length(); i++) {
        int j = (sent.length() - 1);
        count = 0;
        while (j > i) {

            if (sent.charAt(j) == sent.charAt(i)) {
                sent = deleteCharAt(sent, i);
                sent = deleteCharAt(sent, j - 1);
                break;
            }

            j--;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < sent.length(); i++) {
        System.out.println(sent.charAt(i));
    }
}

private static String deleteCharAt(String strValue, int index) {
    return strValue.substring(0, index) + strValue.substring(index + 1);

}
```

```
Enter the sentence:
java is good object oriented programming language
a
v
i
s
o
d
b
c
r
e
e
d
p
g
m
m
n
l
u
```

Comment: Hi. please add also your output.

Comment: That's quite an inefficient algorithm

Comment: @CaiusJard How can i increase the efficiency?

Comment: since `String` is immutable it is better to use `StringBuilder`, `char[]` or even some `Collection` (e.g. `Set` or `List`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably going to want to use a `Set`. These data structures are like `List`s, except:

- They do not have an ordering (meaning you cant call `set.get(3)`)
- They do not allow duplicates

You can think of them as a `Map` without any values.

If you have a `String` and you want to get all the unique `char`s from it. The steps are as follows:

```
String string = "hello";  // 4 unique characters
Set<Character> uniqueChars = new HashSet<>();  // create an empty set to put the unique chars into

// split into char[]
char[] chars = string.toCharArray();

Arrays.stream(chars).forEach(c -> {
    // the following code will be run once for every char in the array

    uniqueChars.add(c);
    // adding the same char twice does not insert it twice
});
```

This can be written more concisely as:

```
String string = "hello";
Set<Character> uniqueChars = new HashSet<>();
Arrays.stream(string.toCharArray()).forEach(uniqueChars::add);  // using a Java 8 method reference
```

If you want to reject any `char` that is a numerical digit, you can use the following line:

```
boolean containsDigit = Arrays.stream(string.toCharArray())
    .filter(Character::isDigit)  // filter out all the non digit characters
    .findAny()  // check if there are any remaining
    .isPresent();
```

Answer (score 2):

To avoid duplicate you can use a `Set`: is a collection that doesn't allow duplicates. You have to use a specific implementation of that interface, such as `HashSet`. You can do something like this:

```
public class UniqueChar {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the sentence:");
    String withoutSpaces = sc.nextLine();
    withoutSpaces = "asc34csf"; // mock example
    Set<Character> goodChars = new HashSet<>();
    String sent = withoutSpaces.replaceAll(" ", "");
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < sent.length(); i++) {
        char currChar = sent.charAt(i);
        // do not add a character if is a digit
        if(Character.isDigit(currChar))
            System.out.println("Digit!");
        else
            goodChars.add(currChar); // add a character only if not present
    }
    String output = "";
    for (Character character : goodChars) {
        output += character; // concat in a single output string
    }

    System.out.println(output);
}
```

So you simply jump characters that are digits, if it's a character it'll be added to the collection (and the `Set` manages internally the fact that if it's a duplicate, it will not be added), then concat the elements of the `Set` in a single String.

---

You can find more information about `HashSet` in the [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html).

Answer (score 2):

It would be more efficient and easier to read code to use a HashSet:

```
    HashSet<Character> h = new HashSet<Character>(); 

    for (int i = 0; i <= (sent.length() - 1); i++) 
        h.add(sent.charAt(i));

    Iterator<Character> i = h.iterator(); 

    while (i.hasNext()) 
        System.out.println(i.next());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write your code something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] alpha = new int[26];
    System.out.println("Enter the sentence:");
    String sent = sc.nextLine().replaceAll(" ", "");
    for (int i = 0; i < sent.length(); i++) {
        int temp = sent[i] - 'a';
        if (temp >= 0 && temp <= 25) {
            alpha[temp] = 1;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid String");
            return;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        if (alpha[i] == 1)
            System.out.println((char) (i + 'a'));
    }
}
```

This uses an array of length 26 as the workaround if you don't want to use any SET like data structure.

This code can bring you problem if your sentence have capital letters as well. You can avoid that problem by using toLowercase like function just before the loop.